# Content is not allowed in trailing section - with struts2-spring-hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

I'm newbie in this framework. I'm starting with some examples/tutorial, but i'm stack now.
I believe that the error is in application-Context.xml, in configuration spring but I don't know where.

I get this error:

```
03-ago-2013 17:29:33 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ListingEventos' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'serviceEvento' of bean class [com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos]: Bean property 'serviceEvento' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'serviceEvento' of bean class [com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos]: Bean property 'serviceEvento' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    ... 56 more
03-ago-2013 17:29:33 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

application-Context.xml only have 60 lines.
Anybody Can Help me?? Thank u very much!

**STRUTS.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> <!-- set to false for prod -->

    <constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="true" />

    <package name="eventos"  namespace="/eventos" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*" class="com.app.struts.actions.eventos.{1}">
            <result name="success">/vistas/eventos/{1}.jsp</result>
            <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectUrl}</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="artistas" namespace="/artistas" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*" class="com.app.struts.actions.artistas.{1}">
            <result>/vistas/artistas/{1}.jsp</result>
            <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectUrl}</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />


</struts>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- The singleton hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean> 

    <!-- Spring's hibernate transaction manager, in charge of making hibernate sessions/txns -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 


    <bean id="eventoDao" class="com.app.dao.EventoDAOImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="eventoService" class="com.app.service.EventoServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg   ref="eventoDao"/>
    </bean>


<bean id="ListingEventos" class="com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos">
    <property name="serviceEvento"  ref="eventoService" />   
</bean>

    </beans>
```

**ListingEventos.java**

```
package com.app.struts.actions.eventos;


import com.app.struts.actions.base.BaseAction;
import com.app.model.Evento;
import com.app.service.IEventoService;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.List;



public class ListingEventos extends ActionSupport {

 protected IEventoService serviceEvento;    
@Override
    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
        eventos = serviceEvento.getEvents();
        return "success";
    }


    List<Evento> eventos;
    public List<Evento> getEvents() { 
        return eventos; 
    }

    public void setServices(IEventoService value) {
        serviceEvento=value;
    }
}
```

**EventoServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.app.service;

import com.app.model.Evento;
import com.app.dao.IEventoDAO;
import java.util.List;


public class EventoServiceImpl implements IEventoService{



    private IEventoDAO dao;

    public EventoServiceImpl(IEventoDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public Evento getEventById(long id){
        return dao.getEventById(id);
    }

    public boolean deleteEventById(long id) {
        return dao.deleteEventById(id);
    }

    public void createEvent(String name) {
        dao.createEvent(name);
    }

    public List<Evento> getEvents(){
        return dao.getEvents();
    }

    public void removePersonFromEvent(int personId, int eventId){
        dao.removePersonFromEvent(personId, eventId);
    }

    public void addPersonToEvent(int personId, int eventId){
        dao.addPersonToEvent(personId, eventId);
    }
public void setEvents(Evento evento){
        dao.setEvents(evento);
    }
}
```

**EventoDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.app.dao;

import com.app.model.Evento;
import com.app.service.IArtistaService;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

public class EventoDAOImpl implements IEventoDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public EventoDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){

        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session sess() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Evento getEventById(long id){

        Query query = sess().createQuery("from com.app.model.evento e where e.id = :ID ");
        //query.setString("ID",Evento.getId());
        Evento EventoOut    = (Evento)query.uniqueResult();
        return EventoOut;
        //return (Evento) sess().load(Evento.class, id);
    }

    public boolean deleteEventById(long id) 
            throws DataAccessException {
        sess().delete(getEventById(id));
        return true;
    }

    public void createEvent(String name) {
        Evento theEvent = new Evento();
        theEvent.setName(name);
        sess().save(theEvent);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Evento> getEvents() {
        return sess().createQuery("from com.app.model.evento").list();
    }

    private IArtistaService iArtistaService;

    public void removePersonFromEvent(int personId, int eventId){
        getEventById(eventId).getPeople().remove(iArtistaService.getPersonById(personId));
    }

    public void addPersonToEvent(int personId, int eventId) {
        getEventById(eventId).getPeople().add(iArtistaService.getPersonById(personId));
    }
public void setEvents(Evento evento){
    long id=evento.getId();
    Query query = sess().createQuery("from com.app.model.evento e where e.id = :ID ");
    Evento EventoOut    = (Evento)query.uniqueResult();
    EventoOut.setName(evento.getName());
    EventoOut.setPeople(evento.getPeople());
}
}
```

**Evento.java**

```
package com.app.model;

import java.util.Set;
import com.app.model.Artista;


public class Evento {


    Long id;

    public Long getId() 
    {return id;}

    public void setId(Long id) 
    {this.id = id;}

    String name;

    public String getName() 
    {return name;}

    public void setName(String value) 
    {name = value;}


    Set<Artista> people;
    public void setPeople(Set<Artista> people) 
    {this.people = people;}

    public Set<Artista> getPeople() 
    {return people;}

}
```

**Evento.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.app.model.Evento" table="events">
        <id name="id" column="Id">
            <generator class="increment">
            </generator>
        </id>
        <!--property name="dt" /-->
        <property name="name" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**structure:**
http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4681/qedu.jpg

Comment: It's very strange that you coupling objects instead of use the spring container.

Comment: i used this tutorial https://github.com/chrishulbert/JavaTutorial/

Comment: It's two years old, why did you modify the constructors? And this tutorial is not what you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned the constructor arguments in the bean xml configuration:

```
   <bean id="ListingEventos" class="com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos">
        <constructor-arg name="eventoService"  ref="eventoService" />   
    </bean>
```

but there is no such construtor in your ListingEventos class file. You need to add the corresponding constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have any constructor in `ListingEventos` taking the argument of type - `IEventoService`. In fact, since you haven't defined any constructor, you just have a default no-arg constructor.

So, you can't inject the bean using `<constructor-arg>` in that bean.

It seems like you should use `<property>` tag to inject using property.

The following bean declaration:

```
<bean id="ListingEventos" class="com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos">
    <constructor-arg name="eventoService"  ref="eventoService" />   
</bean>
```

should be:

```
<bean id="ListingEventos" class="com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos">
    <property name="serviceEvento"  ref="eventoService" />   
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried this before, but i had another error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ListingEventos' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'eventoService' of bean class [com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos]: Bean property 'eventoService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: @LoreLai. Ah! the property name was wrong. Edited code. Try it again, it should work now.

Comment: No :( I only changed constructor-arg by property.. my name is ok

Comment: @LoreLai. Please make sure you use `serviceEvento` in name attribute of property tag.  The name attribute must be same as the name of the variable you used in the bean.

Comment: Is the same...<bean id="eventoService" class="com.app.service.EventoServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg   ref="eventoDao"/>
    </bean>
    
<bean id="ListingEventos" class="com.app.struts.actions.eventos.ListingEventos">
    <property name="eventoService"  ref="eventoService" />   
</bean>

Comment: I'm saying to change the `name` attribute of `<property>` tag to match the property name in `ListingEventos` bean. The `ref` attribute is ok. It should be same as the bean name in which you are injecting.

Comment: Please replace your bean declaration with the one I've posted in my answer

Comment: @LoreLai. Why you still haven't changed the property name? And which one is line number 74 in your application-context.xml?

Comment: application-Context.xml only have 60 lines